# Are typhoons more commonly referred to by number or name?

Tags: words, numbers

Do Japanese ever assign a name to a typhoon, or are they always numbered? In most countries the name is more commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are named according to the conventions, but colloquially they are more or less always referred to by their ordinal number (reset every year).

The only place I personally can remember having seen the names mentioned in Japanese is on the website of Japan's Meteorological Agency (JMA). See e.g. this one:

台風第{たいふうだい｝12号｛ごう｝ (ジョンダリ)

http://www.jma.go.jp/jp/typh/

The JMA has the official responsibility of naming Typhoons in the vicinity of Japan, where they cycle through a list of names. However there is also the PAGASA (Philippines) "unofficially" naming some of them. For details, please see the extensive Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone_naming#Western_Pacific_Ocean_(180%C2%B0_%E2%80%93_100%C2%B0E)

Comment: Numbered domestically and named internationally?

Comment: They are named and numbered by the JMA. I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: It seems like the use of a number is more common in Japan.